# Error in xgb.DMatrix: xgb.DMatrix does not support construction from list

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

I am attempting to train an xgboost classifier while utilizing cross-validation. The code snippet I am about to provide is a component of a larger script, but it specifically pertains to the section where issues have arisen.

```
k <- 10
  
  folds <- createFolds(train_target, k = k, list = TRUE, returnTrain = TRUE)
  
  print('XGBoost part will start now:')
  
  xgb_cv <- function(max_depth, eta, gamma, colsample_bytree, min_child_weight, subsample, nrounds) {
    
    # Initialize a list to store the errors for each fold
    fold_errors <- numeric(k)
    
    # Perform k-fold cross-validation
    for (i in 1:k) {
      # Get the indices for the training and validation sets
      train_indices <- folds[[i]]
      valid_indices <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(train_features)), train_indices)

      # Split the data 
      cv_train_features <- train_features[train_indices, ]
      cv_train_target <- train_target[train_indices]
      cv_valid_features <- train_features[valid_indices, ]
      cv_valid_target <- train_target[valid_indices]

      dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(cv_train_features), label = as.numeric(na.omit(cv_train_target)) - 1)
      dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(cv_valid_features), label = as.numeric(na.omit(cv_valid_target)) - 1)
```

Now you might wonder why did I add `as.matrix` and `as.numeric` arguments. It doesn't make a difference, It's just the same error when I type:

```
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = cv_train_features, label = as.numeric(cv_train_target))
  dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data = cv_valid_features, label = as.numeric(cv_valid_target))
```

The data does not have any NA values, and I made sure the data passed to `xgb.DMatrix` is in the right format. I Viewed the data right before it enters to the function and it is totally fine, `cv_train_features` is a data frame and `cv_train_target` is a vector.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing, nthread = NVL(object$params[["nthread"]],  : 
  xgb.DMatrix does not support construction from list
```

I feel like I've tried everything, I can't find the cause of the problem. The data passed to `xgb.DMatrix` IS NOT a list, then why am I getting this error?